# cipher block chaining / cipher text stealing java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

To gain a better understanding of CBC and CTS im trying to impliment my own class that can encrypt and decrypt without using java's built in CTS Mode. Im using an AES wrapper class as the underlying algorithm but CTS as the mode of operation. So far i have been working on the encryption method but not sure where to go from there. I'm not really sure how to implement the swap of the blocks at end of the CTS mode.

Here is the code i have so far for my encryption method (and dont worry about the AES class it works 100%):

```
    static byte[] encrypt(byte[] ptBytes, javax.crypto.SecretKey key, byte[] IV){

    byte [] ct; 
    byte [] pt;
    byte [] ptBlock, ctBlock;

    //pad the array to proper length
    pt = Arrays.copyOf(ptBytes, (int) (Math.ceil( ( ptBytes.length )/16)*16) );

    //ctBlock = one block of cipher text
    ctBlock = new byte [16];

    //make ct the length of the padded pt 
    ct = new byte [pt.length];

    //do the encryption
    //i is for the current block of plain / cipher text we are on
    for( int i = 1; i < (int) ((Math.ceil( ( ptBytes.length )/16)+1)); i++){
        if( i == 1 ){

            //make ptBlock the first block of the entire plain text
            ptBlock = Arrays.copyOfRange(pt, 0, (i*16)-1);

            //since i = 1 do the XOR to get new plain text with IV
            for (int j = 0; j < ptBlock.length - 1; j++){
                ptBlock[j] = (byte)(ptBlock[j] ^ IV[j]);
            }

            //now time to do the encryption between the current block of plain text and the key
            try {
                ctBlock = AES.encrypt(ptBlock, key);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //now put the cipher text block we just got into the final cipher text array
            for( int k = 0; k < ctBlock.length; k++){
                ct[k] = ctBlock[k];
            }

        }
        else{
            //make ptBlock the current number block of entire plain text
            ptBlock = Arrays.copyOfRange(pt, (i-1)*16, (i*16)-1);

            //now XOR the plain text block with the prior cipher text block
            for(int j = 0; j < ptBlock.length - 1; j++){
                ptBlock[i] = (byte) (ptBlock[j] ^ ctBlock[j]);
            }

            //now time to do the encryption between the current block of plain text and the key
            try {
                ctBlock = AES.encrypt(ptBlock, key);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //now put the cipher text block we just got into the final cipher text array
            for( int k = (i-1)*16; k < (i*16)-1; k++){
                ct[k] = ctBlock[k-16];
            }
        }
    }






    return ct;
}
```

Just if anyone could give some insight into how to finish this method up that would be great because i still am learning the ins and outs of CBC/CTS

Thanks!